# How draw implict 3D surface with sympy?

Tags: sympy

I try to draw `x**2 + y**3 = z**2` use `sympy`, but I don't how to draw it.

I use `plot3d(x**2 + y**3-z**2)` but it  don't work at all, So can someone know how to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, Sympy doesn't support 3d implicit plots. However, `sage` [does](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plot3d/sage/plot/plot3d/implicit_plot3d.html), though I remember it was a very heavy module to install.

Alternatively, if you are using Jupyter Notebook you can use [K3D-Jupyter](https://github.com/K3D-tools/K3D-jupyter/) which is capable of plotting [implicit surfaces](https://k3d-jupyter.org/basic_functionality/Implicit_plot.html). Let's see how to plot your surface:

```py
import k3d
import numpy as np

r = 5
zmin, zmax = -r, r
xmin, xmax = -r, r
ymin, ymax = -r, r
Nx, Ny, Nz = 100, 100, 100

x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, Nx, dtype=np.float32)
y = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, Ny, dtype=np.float32)
z = np.linspace(zmin, zmax, Nz, dtype=np.float32)
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(x, y, z, indexing='ij')
p = x**2 + y**3 - z**2

plot = k3d.plot()
plt_iso = k3d.marching_cubes(p, compression_level=9, xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax,
                             ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax,
                             zmin=zmin, zmax=zmax, level=0.0,
                             flat_shading=False)
plot += plt_iso
plot.display()
```

[image]

Comment: I added this and a recent example to a Jupyter notebook page about the k3d package. You can launch an interactive session with that specific notebook to try it right in your browser **without needing to install anything**, by [clicking here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fomightez/3Dsurface_plot-binder/HEAD?labpath=k3d_surface_examples.ipynb). When the session opens into the notebook, from under `'Run'` on the menubar, select `'Run All'`. The [corresponding 3d surface plots repo](https://github.com/fomightez/3Dsurface_plot-binder#3dsurface_plot-binder).